How to avoid string truncate coming from python print method to node js application
I am running a python script from node JS application as
const { spawnSync } = require('child_process');
const pythonProcess = await spawnSync(python3, [
  scriptFilePath,
  'methodNameToExecute',
  PathList.toString()
]);
const result = pythonProcess.stdout?.toString()?.trim();

The python script is running fine here and getting expected string output from python print method to here in result variable. But when result is too long i am getting truncated string result. Please guide me how to get full string even its too large string. Please guide if any limitation is there while passing string from python to node application.

try setting and increasing maxBuffer option, see: Stdout buffer issue using node child_process

How to set maxBuffer if i am using spawnSync method instead of exec. Can you please guide me @traynor

couldn't find more fitting answer, but spawn/spawnSync also uses that option, so it's same. try this: spawnSync(python3, [...], { maxBuffer: 10000 * 1024 })

Thanks @traynor , I tried as you suggested and it worked for me. Thank you so much..
